# Custom UIViewController Transition with Blur

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to achieve a transition of my UIViewController where is very simply zooms out slightly and blurs so that it sits faded in the background. I have looked at a lot of solutions but I can't find anything surrounding blurring specifically.

Currently I am just playing with taking a screen of the parent view controller and animating that in the child.

Apps such as Tweetbot 3 and Pinterest are notable ones which do this, see a screenshot here, exactly what I mean:

[image]

I'm struggling with it smoothly blur out. Any suggestions on how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS 7 Solution:**

You can display it in UIImageView and place on top of other UIViews. In the past, I used renderInContext in CALayer.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *blurImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Once you capture UIView screenshot, apply blur effect. Unfortunately, there is no public API available yet for blur effect, but Apple has a sample implementation in sample code. It's a Category for UIImage. Please search a sample code in Xcode documentations. After adding UIImage category files to your project, you can blur an image like this:

```
blurImg = [blurImg applyDarkEffect];
```

**Prior to iOS 7 Solution:**
https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS

```
UIImage *blurImg = [originalImg stackBlur:radius];
```

Comment: Yeah I have seen lots of different solutions to blurring an image, including Apples own code. However I bump into another issue. When blurring the UIImage, the blur doesn't extend outside the image bounds, meaning you still get a hard edge.